# How to model this graph correctly using Label Property Graph?

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to create a graph database for my data using Label Property Graph in Neo4j, but I don't know if I modeled my graph correctly or not. I will use this small example to illustrate my problem.

Suppose we have a book with some properties like this:

[image: Book]

From here, it makes sense to model our graph as follow:

[image: LPG Book]

The problem is: **I don't have any control over the properties of the book.** In this example, a book has 7 properties, but maybe another book comes with more or fewer properties, and even with the different name. That's why I don't know how to group those properties into nodes, and which types of nodes will exist in my model. So I decided to create another model, where each property is a node itself. It looks like this:

[image: Book RDF]

(Now it looks like the RDF Triplestores, I think...)

An example instance of this model with 2 books would be:

[image: Book Instance Example]

In this case, we have 2 books with the same `price` and `author_firstName`. At this point, I have some questions:

1. What do you think about this way of modeling? Is it OK? I personally feel that something's wrong because it looks like RDF while I'm using Label Property Graph. It seems that I don't use the power of the LPG at all.
2. **Is it better to make every property a node itself so that we can see more connection in our graph?** If I model this way, I can clearly see the relation between 2 books through the `price` and `author_firstName`, which I cannot see if I model it using the first way. In short, using the first way will not show me any connection between the 2 books in this example.
3. The second option of modeling is also easier for searching, right? E.g. finding all books with `price = 15`: just find a `price` node with value equals 15 and start spreading from that node.

Last but not least, the purpose of this database is for searching.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hi AnhTriet. All depends on your query requirements. Neo4j has a very flexible data model. Take a look in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48708601/6835358).

Comment: Also, it seems you have a much bigger issue if your incoming data has basically random properties. You are going to have to figure out how to normalize the data so that any reasonable queries can be done at all.

Comment: a property graph is **not** RDF, thus, why the RDF tag? "it looks like RDF"? Why? Property graph has nodes with labels, RDF not

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your comment. It seems that the granularity of the graph depends on the problem itself. So there is no absolutely right or wrong answer in model design.